# Getting errors when using cardano-wallet-js --> Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: react

I've been going through the cardano docs at https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-wallet-js to test the interface.  I installed the package using npm without issue and am starting with including the package in my project using:

> const { WalletServer } = require('cardano-wallet-js');

When I save i get the following error:

Compiled with problems:X

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs/cardano_serialization_lib.js 16189:14-40
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Greg\Documents\crypto-app-test\node_modules@emurgo\cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs'

I originally had a number of errors which were fixed by installing various packages.  I tried doing the same with the `fs` package but that did not resolve the issue.

I am on a windows 10 virtual machine using the following:

vs code v1.76.1
node js v16.14.2
react v18.1.0
cardano-wallet-js v1.4.0
cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs v10.0.4

i took a look at the fs package and it seems to be abandoned or deprecated and has the following info in the readme:

> ## Security holding package
>
> This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied
> by another package. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the
> package name, but loosely, and we'll probably give it to you if you
> want it.
>
> You may adopt this package by contacting support@npmjs.com and
> requesting the name.

I do have a running wallet server running on another machine but haven't gotten to the point of trying to connect to it through this js package.  Anyone know what's going on here?